# Reloading a Child Component from within a Higher Order Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am on the last step on a little project that is using a Higher Order Component (HOC) to render a simple Tinder-like application.

The inner component is a class-based component with its own fetch() call that renders data for the user and a picture. The outer HOC is a functional component. All I need to do to get the app to work is find a way to refresh the inner component and trigger the API call when the user presses a button. I am attempting to do this with the `useState` hook in the HOC.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function TinderCard(component) {
  return function (props) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const refresh = () => {
      // change state. set isLoading to true and then back to false.
      setIsLoading(true);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    const C = component;
    return (
      <div className='card  user-card-container'>
        <div className='card-body user-card-inner'>
          {isLoading ? <h3>Loading...</h3> : <C />}
          <div className='buttons-container'>
            <button className='dislike' onClick={() => refresh()}>
              <i className='fa fa-times'></i>
            </button>
            <button className='like' onClick={() => refresh()}>
              <i className='fa fa-heart'></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Everything works fine until I use the useState hook, which stops the app from rendering with a pretty nasty error message. This one:

```
  Line 5:39:  React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

My questions are - (1) how can I use `useState` within an HOC to change state when a button is clicked, and (2) is there an easier way to reload a child component on button press- maybe without using state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to doc https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

- Call Hooks from React function components

In your case your function is not a component, its a function that return a Component

You can change your code to get rid of HOC and use simple composition with `children` prop

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function TinderCard({children}) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const refresh = () => {
      // change state. set isLoading to true and then back to false.
      setIsLoading(true);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    
    return (
      <div className='card  user-card-container'>
        <div className='card-body user-card-inner'>
          {isLoading ? <h3>Loading...</h3> : children}
          <div className='buttons-container'>
            <button className='dislike' onClick={() => refresh()}>
              <i className='fa fa-times'></i>
            </button>
            <button className='like' onClick={() => refresh()}>
              <i className='fa fa-heart'></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  
}
```

then use it like this:

```js
<TinderCard>
  <SomeFriend/>
</TinderCard>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @user1432711. Your answer makes the most sense and of course that would be a much prettier way of accomplishing the same thing. However I'm using the HOC just to practice, so I'd like to find a solution that successfully uses it.

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-6pqw7

It looks like the above answer provided a partial solution to the problem, but I just wanted to point out another gotcha that you might have in your solution. Your refresh function calls setIsLoading twice. This will cause a re-render of your component but it will only occur once and it will only occur after the refresh function has completed execution. Your component will never be rendered with the state variable actually being true. Additionally any effects tied to the useEffect hook for your state variable will also not execute on refresh. See the above code sandbox for an example of how this occurs.

Comment: Thanks @Codeofthewarrior. I actually called setIsLoading twice as a lazy way to force the child component that the HOC wraps to re-render. When it is set to true the DOM will render the JSX element `<h3>Loading...</h3>` and then it is immediately set to false again, forcing the element to re-render. 
I just couldn't think of a shorter way to do this, though ultimately of course it didn't work at all.